# Get process' open files in Windows 10 using psutil in Python

Tags: python, windows-10, handle, psutil

I am trying to get all the open files of a process in Windows 10 using Python.
This is my code-

```
import psutil
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
       print proc.open_files()
```

It works in Windows 7 but in Windows 10 I get empty arrays for all of the processes.
Does anyone know what's the problem?